# Can you set the default button of a panel with a button that is not in that panel but in another content placeholder in a master page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

Can you set the default button of a panel with a button that is not in that panel but in another content placeholder within a master page? I have tried this but I get the following error:

The DefaultButton of 'pnlTmp' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl.

I have also tried setting the panels DefaultButton this way :

```
  pnlTmp.DefaultButton = btnContinue.UniqueID
```

This gave me the same error.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Try for this issue Master page properties:

```
    Page.Master.Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnButton.UniqueID

    ' if first doesn't help
    Page.Master.Page.Form.DefaultFocus = btnButton.ClientID
```

Comment: @Geezuz Mark his answer as correct if it helped you out good sir!